# how to eliminate zero's in a column using t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am struck at the below requirement, can anybody please guide me with the syntax for this below condition.

```
For Class Number Display, display CLASS_NO with no leading zeros
```

actual values in this field are

```
ex: 001
    002
    003
    014
```

i should get the output as

```
'1'
'2'
'3'
'14'
```

can anybody please help me with the syntax ?

Comment: How about casting them to INT?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply `CAST` them to `INT`:

```
SELECT CAST('001' AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to an INT and then back to the original Datatype:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('001' AS INT) AS <Original Datatype>)
```